# Check if value change event was triggered by user

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a slider control and both the app and user will be making adjustments. The slider will trigger the ValueChanged event when the value changes, but I only want to trigger that if it was from the user ie, mouse or keyboard input changed it. I guess I could do it the hard way and check mouse and keyboard events and set a bool but I'd rather handle it all in one event if possible.

How do I check who changed the value?

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) {
   if(wasUser) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way is to take advantage of the fact that event-handlers are called synchronously via property-setters - so set a field (accessible by all the handlers) to selectively ignore events if the current event was indirectly raised by a previous event-handler instead of direct user action.

Consider a textbox that can have its text set by the program, or typed-in by the user:

```
class MyWindow : Window {

    private Boolean isIndirectEvent = false;

    void Timer_Tick() {

        this.isIndirectEvent = true;
        this.TextBox.Text = "foo"; // TextBox_TextChanged will be invoked inside this property's setter
        this.isIndirectEvent = false;
    }

    void TextBox_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

        if( this.isIndirectEvent ) return;

        this.InvokeTurboEncabulator();
    }
}
```

(Of course, the "best" approach would be to use MVVM, Dependency Properties and Data Bindings which completely obviates this entire class of problems, but that requires making significant changes to your program, fwiw).

Comment: I decided to go ahead and do this. If the program is updating i set "UserChangedValue" to false.